# Can not understand the return of this function in C++

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me to understand this function?

```
CheckList(Listfile*& Listitems,bool showSortList)
```

`Listfile` is a class but I can't understand what is `Listfile*&`, what would be return to `Listitems`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [reference to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/1938163):

```
CheckList(Listfile*& Listitems,bool showSortList)
          ^^^^^^^^^ pointer to Listfile
                   ^ reference
```

you should study C++ better, this can be found in [any decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: +1. Additionally, phrases like "any decent C++ book" are best accompanied with a link to the [list of good C++ books here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: im studing/using C++ simultaneously, at least step by step try to understand this language now. Thanks you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Its taking `reference of pointer to Listfile`. Have a look here for detail of this topic:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4894/Pointer-to-Pointer-and-Reference-to-Pointer

[Passing references to pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823426/passing-references-to-pointers-in-c)