# How are addresses of objects created on the stack temporary

Tags: c++

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823426/passing-references-to-pointers-in-c) question and I would like to know why the address of a non constant string created on the stack of a method returns a constant pointer when its address is requested. I have copy-pasted the code sample used there

```
void myfunc(string*& val)
{
    // Do stuff to the string pointer
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    string s;
    myfunc(&s);
    // ...
}
```

My question is that `&` returns the address of a variable. So In the above case the `std::string s` is a `non constant` then why is it returning its address as a constant ? What I want to know is why the address of the non-constant string is returned as a constant address. Are the addresses of all objects created on the stack constant ?

Comment: Dont know the reason for a down-vote.

Comment: A `string const*` ponter can still point to a non const instance, it's unclear what you're asking about. The variable itself being `const` has nothing to do with constness of it's address.

Comment: AFAIK, *& does nothing. You are grabbing the value of a pointer from its reference, thus, the same thing as grabbing only the `string` value.

Comment: Maybe because you question is err... 'unclear'?

Comment: Ill put more detail into the question

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ῥεῖ are you saying that an object created on the stack always has a constant address ?

Comment: In what way is it returning the address as a constant?

Comment: @Rajeshwar, put it this way, what should modifying the address of a variable mean?

Comment: *Every* object has a constant address. If you change the address (e.g. by moving or copying), you have a different object.

Comment: @Rajeshwar _"are you saying that an object created on the stack always has a constant address ?"_ Yup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you did:

```
void myfunc(string*& val)
{
    val = NULL;
    // How is that supposed to affect the variable s in main?
    // You can't change the address of the object in main.
    // Once a variable is created, its address cannot be modified.
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    string s;

    // Since the address of s cannot be changed,
    // the type of &s is "string* const" not "string&".

    // That's why the call to myfunc is wrong.
    myfunc(&s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. So you are saying that an object when created on the stack actually has a constant address.

Comment: @Rajeshwar, addresses of objects, whether they are on the stack or they are global are constant.

Comment: `&s` is prvalue of type `string *` and reference to lvalue of type `string *` (parameter type of your function) cannot be bound to it