# Declaring reference to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am trying to declare a reference variable to a pointer.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int m = 10;
 int *p = &m;
 int & ref = p; // this is showing error
 }
```

I am reading a c++ book and in the book i saw this code, but this is showing an error.
It is supposed to set ref as a reference variable to point to pointer p and in turn point to m.

Comment: If this is the exact code in the book, then it's a mistake

Comment: Change `int & ref = p;` to `int* & ref = p;`.

Comment: ^ --- Or `int &ref = *p;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing references to pointers in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823426/passing-references-to-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the asterisk `*` at the *reference to pointer* declaration:

```
int *p = &m;
int *&ref = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m = 10;
    int *p = &m;
    int *& ref = p; //read from right to left,so *& is a refrence to pointer
}
```