# Difference between TreeNode* root and TreeNode* &root

Tags: c++, pointers

I have seen some people use the `TreeNode* &root` while passing as a parameter in function while I use the `TreeNode* root`.

Is there a difference or is it the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823426/passing-references-to-pointers-in-c

Comment: There is in fact an essential difference: `TreeNode*& root` is a reference to a pointer. Changes of `root` will bail out. That's not the case for `TreeNode* root`. The pointer (itself) is passed by value, i.e. changing the pointer has only local effect. Please note, that this is about the pointer itself but not the contents where it points to.

Comment: *I have seen some people use* -- Looks like you're using online coding websites to learn C++.  A good C++ book explains what this is -- you won't learn C++ by using sites that parcel out random puzzle questions.

Comment: Put another way, parameter `TreeNode* root` is a **copy** of the pointer.  `TreeNode* &root` is not a copy.

Comment: The same as the difference between `int` and `int&`. There is nothing special about pointers.